# Create record from discriminated union types

Tags: typescript

So I have a bunch of types like so:

```
interface ReadyMessage {
    type: 'ready';
}
interface ProgressMessage {
    type: 'progress';
    message: string;
}
interface DoneMessage {
    type: 'done';
}
```

and I create a union of that type like this:

```
type Message = ReadyMessage | ProgressMessage | DoneMessage;
```

How do I create a Record, where the keys are `Message['type']` and the values are the corresponding type.

i.e.

```
type Matchers = {
  ready: { type: 'ready'; };
  progress: { type: 'progress'; message: string; };
  done: { type: 'done'; }
}
```

Doing something like `type Matchers = Record<Message['type'], Message>` but this results in the value type being `Message` instead the more specific `ProgressMessage`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to use a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types) where the value type is dependent on the key.  (The [`Record`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkt) utility type is a mapped type, but the value type is completely independent of the key, as you've seen.)  You can extract a member from a discriminated union using [the `Extract` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#extracttu):

```
type Matchers = {
  [K in Message['type']]: Extract<Message, { type: K }>
};
```

You can verify that it produces what you're looking for:

```
/* type Matchers = {
    ready: ReadyMessage;
    progress: ProgressMessage;
    done: DoneMessage;
} */
```

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEoTgEwJ4FkIDOBcA5igN4BQyyY2ADhAFzIDkUGOrA3JQL6VQkWIhQAFKAHsSHIviKkK1Wg2Zt6UmYQI9lAW22KWBMFFAleAodHhJkAEUkgI84mWRUadRi1aYnELoClJTeKK6KyAC8aJx4hu4APsgS0rIEEUkOAZkQvKGqyLhwYAgAFtAE0R7KANoA0sigRQkQtaxhrAC6XSwAogAepohgADy5ADQeKj7IjXwAfPz5APQAVDPhJeWV1Z40yBxY2Czox7m8B8gaadosqVpyrZcH-s4sjs4X-MhrK8hAA)